# Images are not shown in Odoo v9.0 / python 2.7

Tags: python, odoo, werkzeug

In a freshly installed Odoo 9 (https://github.com/odoo/odoo) contact and product images wont display.
I am unable to change them too, generating an notification "image can not be displayed"

In another similar case i found was a solution to upgrade werkzeug

the werkzeug was already up to date.

```
pip install --upgrade werkzeug
Requirement already up-to-date: werkzeug in ./lib/python2.7
```

below is an isolated part of the log

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=1998): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/josesapelli/webapps/odoo/odoo/openerp-wsgi.py'.
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/josesapelli/webapps/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-9.0-py2.7.egg/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 184, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
   File "/home/josesapelli/webapps/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-9.0-py2.7.egg/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 170, in application_unproxied
     result = handler(environ, start_response)
   File "/home/josesapelli/webapps/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-9.0-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 1416, in __call__
     return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
   File "/home/josesapelli/webapps/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-9.0-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 1390, in __call__
     return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
   File "/home/josesapelli/webapps/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wsgi.py", line 588, in __call__
     return self.app(environ, start_response)
   File "/home/josesapelli/webapps/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-9.0-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 1586, in dispatch
     return response(environ, start_response)
   File "/home/josesapelli/webapps/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 1207, in __call__
     start_response(status, headers)
   File "/home/josesapelli/webapps/odoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-9.0-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 1389, in start_wrapped
     start_response(status, new_headers)
 ValueError: no space following status code
```

anyone got some ideas?